# Showing blog content using Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best way to show Blog content using Razor in Asp.Net MVC 4 ?
I would like to show the spaces and the line breaks in what ever format the user saves the data.

Currently i am using a Para tag and its not showing the line breaks and spaces.

This is what i have now.

```
<p  class="postcontentpara"  >
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(@item.PostText)
</p>

 .postcontentpara
  {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  }
```

Comment: You need to add the details of your blog content. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

@Html.Raw("your blog content")